# How to add a column for percentage using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to add a column for percentage using a stored procedure. I got the column for total marks of a student but percentage is not being calculated. I have different subject marks in a table called `tbl_Marks` and then I wrote a stored procedure for adding a total column.

Here is my code for the stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_TotalMarks]
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @t int
   DECLARE @p int

   SET @t = 300
   SET @p = 100

   SELECT 
      Student_Id, Stu_Name, Maths, English, Hindi,
      (Maths + English + Hindi) AS 'Total',
      ((Maths + English + Hindi )/@t)* @p AS 'Percentage'
   FROM 
      tbl_Marks
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_TotalMarks]

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @t numeric(8,2)
DECLARE @p int

SET @t = 300
SET @p = 100
SELECT 
Student_Id,
Stu_Name,
Maths,
English,
Hindi,
(Maths + English + Hindi) AS 'Total',
CAST(CAST((Maths + English + Hindi) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) / @t * 100 AS NUMERIC(8,2)) AS 'Percentage'

FROM tbl_Marks
END
```

If you want to persist percentage result, then add new column in table, which will be calculated, add a formula an check to persist result for better performance.

Comment: I didn't know about CAST keyword in sql. That's really helpful.

Comment: There are `CAST` and `CONVERT` conversion functions, which are similar, but have some distinction. Later has possibility to add third parameter to give some style to output

Comment: If there are 100 students in a class and I want to display the percentage of each one of them  then this SP will be time consuming. Earlier I was trying to add a column of percentage  in tbl_Marks itself.Is it possible to implement trigger in the store procedure which is called on 'INSERT' or 'UPDATE' operation on the tbl_Marks. I have never used trigger actually. If you could explain me the solution of this problem with a query It would be great. Thanks in advance.